# Hangfire recurring job failed without any mention

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I use SQL Server to store Hangfire data and self-written logger to log all stuff from Hangfire of my ASP.NET MVC 5 site. The problem is I can startup Hangfire, configure it, add new recurring job without any problems, but it just doesn't work (failed state in `Hangfire.Job` table).

I use this `OwinStartup` configuration:

```
public static void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app, string connectionName)
{
    var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    };

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionName, options);

    // Do not try to rerun failed jobs by default!
    GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });

    // Add logs into passed log
    LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new MyLogProvider()));

    app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I make it work?
2. Why do I not get any log error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I've found out answers to all questions:

First of all, my logging became work after I had commented this line:

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
```

I've tried to change Attempts to 1, but it still has not worked. Only full commenting of this code helped. Is this a bug? Frankly, I think so.

And after commenting I've got an opportunity to receive a problem message. And the problem is the class which owns called method isn't contains parameterless constructor.